# How to make a box with title and controls?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Twitter Bootstrap 3 how can I create a box (DIV) that has a title, and below the title a row for icons or text, and below that an area for text?

For example:

```
 --------------
| My Title     |
|--------------|
| Print | Edit |
|--------------|
| This is the  |
| body of my   |
| DIV box.     |
 --------------
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This can be done several ways. Here are a few options:

First, is a *modal*. That doesn't seen to be your goal necessarily though:

- **Modals:** http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Next is a *list group*, which seems closer:

- **List Groups:** http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group

The closest one to what it seems like you want is a *panel*:

- **Panels:** http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels